# Slow evaluation of large matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, programming, iterators

I have been trying to evaluate the matrix `ce[n]` in the code below but it is taking too long and still running as you increase `n` (still running since 6 hours only for `n=5`). I am interested to calculate `ce[n]` for `n=10`. Does anyone have a suggestion to solve the issue? Your support much appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
phi[x_]:=Piecewise[{{1,0<=x<1},{0,True}}]

psi1[x_] := (phi[2 x] - phi[2 x - 1]);

psijk[x_, j_, k_] := Piecewise[{{(Sqrt[2])^j psi1[2^j x - k],0 <= j}, {(2)^j psi1[2^j (x - k)], j <= -1}}]

PSI[j_, k_, l_, s_] := Integrate[psijk[x, j, k]*psijk[x, l, s], {x, -1, 1}] - 
Integrate[x*t*(1 + x*t)*psijk[t, j, k]*psijk[x, l, s], {x, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}]

ce[n_] =: ArrayReshape[
   Table[PSI[j, k, l, s], {j, -n, n}, {k, -2^n, (2^n)-1}, {l, -n, n}, {s,-2^n, (2^n)-1}], {(2n+1)2^(n+1), (2n+1)2^(n+1)}];
```

Comment: So you want to generate 1.7 billion entries. Is that correct? From your indices in `Table`; `n = 10;
2 n*(2*2^n - 1)*2 n*(2*2^n - 1)`.

Comment: @Edmund it is 1849688064 entries if n=10. For n=5 it is 495616 entries but it is still running. The size of the matrix will be

 `(2n+1)2^(n+1) by (2n+1)2^(n+1)`

Comment: I was just checking that you knew how many entries you where creating.

Comment: @Edmund So from your experience is it possible to find a solution for the issue?

Comment: You will need a lot of memory. With my rough calculation of 16 bytes per entry you will need 27Gb to store the result; `n = 10;
len = 2 n*(2*2^n - 1)*2 n*(2*2^n - 1);
N@UnitConvert[Quantity[len 16, "Bytes"], "Gigabytes"]`.  But some of the more experienced people here could tell you more.

Comment: Also, try [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) and `phi` should use [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) and not [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html).

Comment: @Bill so dear Bill how to skip the reshape? I'm in fact need to find `pseudoinverse [ce]* certain vector`, that is only what I need and I don't want to store the huge matrix. How I can do that?

Comment: I put the new definition of Boole you provided but I got the following error:
`"Tag Times in for\ is\ n\ GeoPosition[{24.47,54.37}] is Protected."`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60247/discussion-between-mutaz-and-edmund).